# Order by con case when

Tags: sql, sql-server

intento realizar la siguiente consulta pero después de horas de intentarlo no logro hacerlo, mi consulta es la siguiente:

```
    SELECT * FROM( 
            SELECT '' AS des_planeacion, -1 AS idu_planeacion, '1999-01-01' as fec_inipreplaneacion, 1 as clv_activa UNION ALL
            SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT des_planeacion, idu_planeacion, fec_inipreplaneacion, clv_activa FROM cat_planeaciones
            WHERE opc_mostrar = 1
        ) A ORDER BY (
            CASE WHEN clv_activa = 1 THEN fec_inipreplaneacion END
        ) ASC,
        ( CASE WHEN clv_activa = 0 THEN fec_inipreplaneacion END) DESC
```

Lo que deseo realizar es, que aparezcan primero los registros donde clv_activa es igual a 1, y estos registros ordenarlos por el campo fec_inipreplaneación ASC, cuando clv_activa es igual a 0, estos deben aparecer después de todos los registros de clv_activa, además deben de ordenarse por el campo fec_inipreplaneación también, pero de forma DESC, he realizado varios intentos pero no lo he podido realizar

con ese Query el resultado no es el deseado, me aparecen abajo los del campo clv_activa = a 1, cuando deberían aparecer primero que los del 0

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A ver, ¿por qué usas `UNION ALL` en esta consulta? ¿Podrías ofrecernos un ejemplo mínimo y verificable de tus datos, mucho mejor a través de un fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Te complicas la vida porque quieres. Puedes escribir todo de la manera más sencilla y funciona. No necesitas usar subconsultas o `TOP 100 PERCENT` o `CASE`. Lo único que necesitas es referenciar las columnas por alias en el `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT '' AS des_planeacion, 
        -1 AS idu_planeacion, 
        '1999-01-01' as fec_inipreplaneacion, 
        1 as clv_activa 
UNION ALL
SELECT des_planeacion, 
        idu_planeacion, 
        fec_inipreplaneacion, 
        clv_activa 
FROM cat_planeaciones
WHERE opc_mostrar = 1
ORDER BY clv_activa DESC, 
         fec_inipreplaneacion;
```

Comment: Me sigo preguntando cuál es el propósito de usar `UNION ALL` para esta consulta ¿?

Comment: Por el nombre de la tabla, parece ser parte de un datawarehouse. Esto permite poder asociar filas que no tengan una planeación asociada a una fila vacía. Al menos en SSAS, así se evitan errores al procesar los cubos.

Comment: Tambíen puede ser para que aparezca un valor vacío al construir un combobox.